# How to use Provider without BuildContext?

Tags: flutter

I have an authProvider (extends ChangeNotifier) with login() and logout() methods.
I have also an apiProvider (with Dio) and for all Eror than i catch for each request, if it's a 401 i will fire the logout() method into the authProvider.
But i don't have the context so it seems impossible.

How can i do ?

MAIN (partial)

```
main() {
  GetIt.I.registerSingleton<ApiProvider>(ApiProvider());
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => AuthProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Serialtrip',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: defaultTheme,
        home: _showScreen(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _showScreen(BuildContext context) {
  switch (context.watch<AuthProvider>().loggedInStatus) {
    case Status.Authenticating:
      return Splash();
    case Status.LoggedIn:
      return Home();
    default:
      return Login();
  }
}
```

APIPROVIDER

```
class ApiProvider {
  final dioClient.Dio _client = new dioClient.Dio();
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

  dioClient.Dio get client => _client;

  ApiProvider() {
    _client.options.baseUrl = BACKEND_URI;
    _client.options.connectTimeout = 2000; //2s
    _client.options.receiveTimeout = 2000; //2s
    _client.interceptors.add(dioClient.InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (dioClient.RequestOptions options) async {
      String token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
      options.headers = {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
      };
      return options;
    }, onError: (dioClient.DioError e) async {
      if (dioClient.DioErrorType.RESPONSE == e.type && 401 == e.response.statusCode) {
        print('401 -> deconnexion !');
        // Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).logout();
      } else {
        showSimpleNotification(
          Text('${e.type} - ${e.error}'),
          position: NotificationPosition.bottom,
        );
      }
      return e;
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a buildContext available. It's the `create` argument

Comment: i don't have create into ApiProvider it's juste a service :(

Comment: Why don't you pass the `context` with construct?

Comment: how ? i have only the GetIt to access to the service : GetIt.I.registerSingleton<ApiProvider>(ApiProvider()); look my main() and at this moment i dont have the context. Flutter is very complexe with the context :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution but i don't know if  it's a good method.

In the main.dart into the build I use

```
GetIt.instance<ApiProvider>().initContext(context);
```

So into the apiProvider i have now the BuildContext and i can call the method into je AuthProvider like this :

```
_context.read<AuthProvider>().logout();
```

But the inject of the context fire same times. But i have no other solution and it's work !